# How can I pass a value from one page so that my "Row text contains" filter is enabled in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

Is there any way in Oracle APEX where we can pass a value from one page to other page, and in the other page it emulates the filter same as "Row text contains". 
For eg:

Page A --->  clicks on a link to call Page B and Passes a value '12345' to this new page.

And then
Page B opens up with all the values where row text contains '12345'

I have created a hidden field 'P17812_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER' on page B.
When I click on a link on Page A, I set the value in this field. 
Now, I created a dynamic action on "page load" on page B. Where i write the below code :

```
$("#apexir_SEARCH").val($v("P17812_EMPLOYEE_NUMBER"));
gReport.search("SEARCH");
```

But this also doesn't work.

Is there any way we can implement this scenario?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IR_ROWFILTER in URL as a parameter and in parameter values the value that you want to filter like:

```
?p=App:Page:Session:Request:Debug:ClearCache:IR_ROWFILTER:12345:PrinterFriendly
```

You can read more about APEX url in here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/concept_url.htm#HTMDB03019

and about IR filter https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMDB/linking-to-interactive-reports.htm

Comment: You can also do this: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_ir.htm#AEAPI29339

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden page item on page B, have the link set value to the item when you click on it
then have the same select statement from page A on B with a where clause

SELECT a, b, c
  FROM test
...
 WHERE b = %ITEM%

(THE % tells him that it can be whatever text or no text there)
and dont forget to pass the item to the sql query

I hope I understood what you want, and that my answer is understandable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I do not want the value to be passed for a specific column  like 'b' in your case. I want to filter - If the row contains my search value anywhere in the row , in any column, not any one particular column..

Comment: Well the other users have given you great answers, but if you wanna go with the simplest method(the one I described) you could also just do my way with OR statements so you check every collumn.